# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:java

Tags: java, string

```
public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1=new String("hello welcome to java world");
        int count=s1.length();
        System.out.println(count);

        for(int i=count;i>count-1;i--) {
            char j=s1.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the above program I'm getting the error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 27
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at ReverseString.main(ReverseString.java:12)
```

can any one clarify where exactly I am going wrong in the code?

Comment: Let's say length of the string is about 10. then what? your for loop would be: for(int i=10;  i>10-1; i--). do you see a problem? the condition will always be true: 10>10-1... 9>9-1... 8>8-1...

Comment: yeah @Andrey i got the point where i gone  wrong :) many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop should be

```
for(int i=count-1;i>=0;i--)
```

Since accessing the

```
s1.charAt(count) => s1.charAt(s1.length())
```

would throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` reason being index based from `0` the string would be contained withing the `length-1` index.

Comment: @Shiva If it helps, do mark an answer(select the tick) that can help future readers as well.